# How does the flow work with associated domains, behavior is not allways same for all devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

We are testing an issue with associated domains, mainly focusing on ios devices.   Feature was added to support deep linking.  But trying to understand the behavior.

Let's say you have a domain.

http://mydomainyy.com and url
http://mydomainyy.com/theapp

And configuration at url:

https://mydomainyy.com/ ..... /apple-app-site-association

With values:

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": [ "abc.myapp"],
             "components": [
               {
                  "/": "/theapp/*"                  
               }
             ]
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

The behavior we are seeing, almost like smart banner? comes into play,

We see a banner at top of mobile browser, "Open your app"

But sometimes if you visit that URL, it "auto open the application" and there is no prompt.  We are trying to ssee if it will NOT open automatically.  We would like a prompt into the app from browser to app.

It looks like different version of ios, the behavior is different.

Looking at the documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains